# How can I make a stack-overflow style user URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to map:

`mywebsite.com/users/` -> `mywebsite.com/users/users.php`
`mywebsite.com/users` -> `mywebsite.com/users/users.php`
`mywebsite.com/users/username` -> `mywebsite.com/users/user.php?name=username`

At present, I'm using this .htaccess in the users directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_])*$ user.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ users.php [L]
```

However, it never generates the `user.php?name=$1` URL.

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the rules (place in **.htaccess in website root folder**. If placed elsewhere some tweaking is required):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# 1
RewriteRule ^users/?$ /users/users.php [L]

# 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/users?\.php
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)$ /users/user.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

1. Rule #1 will match fist 2 URLs of yours.
2. Rule #2 will work with specific user mapping. It will ensure that it does not rewrite already rewritten URLs.

---

**UPDATE:**
If you want to place it into .htaccess file in `/users/` folder, then this URL `mywebsite.com/users` (without trailing slash) most likely will not work.

But in any case -- here are the rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# 1
RewriteRule ^$ users.php [L]

# 2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/users?\.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ user.php?name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: How do I tweak them to work in the users subdirectory? I'm never too sure which bits are absolute and which are relative

Comment: @Eric See my updated answer and note that `mywebsite.com/users` (no trailing slash `/` at the end of `users`) most likely will not work (but that depends on other Apache configuration directives) but will work if rules are in root .htaccess.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html _"The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements."_

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it is applying both rules in sequence: the url matches the first rule, so it adds `user.php?name=$1`, and then it matches the second rule, so it replaces the string with `users.php`. If that is the problem, then for your particular case you could fix it by replacing the second regular expression with `^/?$`.